# unable to delete Azure Active Directory custom domain

Tags: azure

The delete option from Azure Active Directory custom Domain is disabled. I suspect that it might be due to my disabled free subscription. Any help with deleting this custom domain is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original domain like `contoso.onmicrosoft.com` cannot be removed or any top-level domain that has subdomains associated with it cannot be removed until the subdomains have been removed. For other custom domain name, you must change or delete any such resource in your Azure AD directory before you can delete the custom domain name. Only a **Global Administrator** can manage domains in Azure AD. Make sure you have enough permission to do this.

To delete a custom domain name, you must first ensure that no resources in your directory rely on the domain name. You can't delete a domain name from your directory if:

> - Any user has a user name, email address, or proxy address that includes the domain name.
> - Any group has an email address or proxy address that includes the domain name.
> - Any application in your Azure AD has an app ID URI that includes the domain name.

You could get more references [here1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/domains-manage#delete-a-custom-domain-name) and [here2](https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-add-domain-delete-domain.md).

Comment: after spending whole day i finally figured out.  if the custom domain is marked as primary domain then the delete is disabled. im not sure why microsoft designed it this way. They need to add a note  in their documentation

Comment: From the [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/domains-manage#set-the-primary-domain-name-for-your-azure-ad-directory) I provided in my reply, `The primary domain is the default domain name for a new user when you create a new user. Setting a primary domain name streamlines the process for an administrator to create new users in the portal.` This implicitly indicated that the primary domain could not be removed as the new user will inherit the domain or the existing users has a domain suffix associated with that domain.

Comment: @sapnashetty - good callout.  Upvoting the question!

Comment: Right, if it's the primary domain it can't be deleted.  You need to create a new domain, set that as primary, then delete old.

Answer (score 2):

Custom domain from Azure AD will not be removed until the custom domain is primary. Make your other domain having extension as onmicrosoft.com as primary and then you should be able to remove the custom domain from Azure AD. Hope this helps.